# How to apply filter component on a JSON api call (Lazyload, Vuejs, Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have got an table with a few filter components, and an fetch to my laravel back-end to cough up the data. What i currently have is that the filter functions are applied on the table data in the front-end but my colleague just told me that we are going to have a million records so it has to get lazyload so it only loads the records that are viewable.

- How do i apply a filter function to an fetch api call? I want the data to get filtered and then send to Vue.

I have no clue what to seek, "vue lazyload api call" doesn't show up what im looking for on Google.

---

my fetch call to laravel database:

```
       getCoinRecords(api_url) {
            api_url = api_url || '/api/support/list';
            fetch(api_url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    this.coins = response.data;
                })
        },
```

my vue filter function:

```
 data() {
    return {
        coins: [],
        filterResult: {},
    }
},
computed: {
    dynFilter(){
        let items = this.coins;
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.filterResult)) {
                if(value != ""){
                    items = items.filter(coin =>{
                        if (coin[key] == value){
                            return coin[key];
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        return items;
    },
}
```

Comment: how is your filter data structured?

Comment: I guess what you want to look for is pagination? If you don't want to view all one million+ rows at the same time then that's what you need. Fetch the rows in chunks and implement some kind of pagination interface.

Comment: @Terry Can u give more info how i can do such thing?

Comment: @mrhn U mean how my json structure looks like?

Comment: You need to have some filters in vuejs how are these structured?

Comment: First of all your API shouldn't be returning all rows. Maybe a limited number, say, 25 per request. Then you can return the next 25 rows on the next page. So on and so forth. [vue-paginate](https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate) is one of those plugins that you could use, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Terry i got 1 million records. I have to filter through them. not just paginate. How do i give parameters to my fetch so it will give only the data i filtered on.

Comment: Provide additional data in your fetch request payload to perform the filtering. Ideally the filtering should be done on the server side: sending all one million records to the client and then filtering them on the client is expensive and inefficient.

Comment: @terry yes and how do i do that. can u send me links of good clear examples.